# jQuery Double-click event display pop-window with aggregated data？

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to display pop-window with aggregated data when Double-click event in jQuery?I use below code to get aggregated data, each `quessionId` has many related `reasons`. when I click/choose questionId button/event, OnClick select questionId and Double-click to remove/cancel, when `OnClick` select a `questionId`, related reasons dictonary will display below questionId, if `Double-click` remove that `questionId`, and related reasons dictonary will display in a `pop-windows' as below picture(User can click 'Confirmed' button after 5
seconds, when confimed, closed pop-windows automatically).

[image: pop-windows pic]

Below is my partial code of `.js` code in jQuery, all related data is fine by below code:

```
function fmtQuestionsByID(id,callback){
    if(!DATA.questions[id] || !$('#card_'+id) )return;
    var project = DATA.projects[DATA.questions[id].projectId];
    if(!project)return;
    
    var issueQuestionLists = DATA.alltags.reduce(function(a,b){
        if(a[b['quessionId']]) {
            a[b['quessionId']].push({name:b['name'],color:b['color'],description:b['description'],reason:b['reason'],question:b['question'],issueId:b['issueId'],department:b['department'],_id:b['quessionId']})
        } else{
            a[b['quessionId']] = [{name:b['name'],color:b['color'],description:b['description'],reason:b['reason'],question:b['question'],issueId:b['issueId'],department:b['department'],_id:b['quessionId']}]
        }
        return a;
    },{});
    var d = 0;
    for(var i=0;i < DATA.questions[id].tags.length;i++){
        var lid = DATA.questions[id].tags[i];

        for(var l in issueQuestionLists){
            var lb = issueQuestionLists[l]
            for(var c=0;c< lb.length;c++){
                var lc = lb[c];
                if(lc._id == lid){
                    d++;
                    var info = lc;
                    console.log('info', info);
                    $('.tags_question').append(d + '['+info.name+']' + info.description + '。' +  'Reason: '+info.reason+ '。' ||'[no data]' );
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Below code to OnClick to select and Double-click to remove.

```
function _fmtQuetionTags(){
    fmtUsers( DATA.lastShowID ,function(html){
        html = '<span class="add_plus_pic question projectinfo_addquestion" title="" href="#" aria-label=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>' + html;
        $('#projectinfoUsers').html( html );

        $('#projectinfoUsers .js-question').attr('title','Double-click remove question').unbind().on('dblclick',function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            doSubmitSetQuestion(DATA.questionid,DATA.lastID,id,function () {
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And I use below html to get above data

```
<div id="questioninfo">
    <span class="tags_question"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to listen for a Double Click?

Comment: @Twisty Hi, yes, how to let those aggregate data display in pop-windows and it must be listened for a double click. Now Double click works fine when select or remove field.

Comment: Am not sure I understand what you need help with then. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty It's a risk warning pop windows.... I am really trying hard to let my question clearly Anyway, thank you so much for reading my post.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the Pop-up that you're trying to work with? I don't see where you have your `click` or `dblclick` events.

Comment: Could you pleasse show me the train of thought? I don't have example of the pop-up, I an new of js/jquery, if you need more details, please feel free to type here, thanks

Comment: I am not sure where to begin. There is not enough substance to understand the question, let alone provide a train of thought regarding a solution. There are so many things undefined in your example, like `DATA` that I have to ask for a better example.

Comment: @Twisty Got it, thanks, we would like to choose plan B, for this is really urgent. Do you know how to let a function wok after 5 seconds? I use setTimeout(), but no matter I changed, it will Reverse jQuery effect after a given time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I created the following example code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#showAlert").click(function() {
    $(".alert.dialog").show("fast", function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert.dialog button[disabled]").prop("disabled", false);
      }, 5000);
    });
  });
  $(".ok.btn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".dialog").hide("fast", function() {
      $(".ok", this).prop("disabled", true);
    });
  });
  $(".dialog li").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("marked").addClass("selected");
  }).dblclick(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("selected").addClass("marked");
  })
});
```

```css
.alert {
  width: 340px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.response {
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.button-set {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-set .default {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #FF0;
}

.marked {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showAlert">Alert</button>
<div class="alert dialog">
  <div class="title">Alert 1</div>
  <div class="response">This is an alert description
    <ul>
      <li>Option 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button-set">
    <button class="ok btn default" disabled="disabled">Okay</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this is similar to what you're doing and what type of functions you're trying to achieve. This example makes use of various methods, `.click()` and `.dblclick()`. It also uses `setTimeout()` in the callback for `.show()`.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/click/
- https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/
- https://api.jquery.com/show/
- https://api.jquery.com/hide/
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Hi, I already gave up this question Thank you so much for your help, I have a function called `doSubmitSetQuestion(DATA.questionid,DATA.lastID,id,function () `, can it take effect after use clicked 'okay'?

Comment: And I only use `dblclick`, I don't know how to use your code in my project

Comment: I will test it tommorrow, do you know how to count click about dblclick and do something after 4 clicks in jQuery? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422038/how-to-count-click-about-dblclick-and-do-something-after-4-clicks-in-jquery?noredirect=1#comment112147629_63422038